Definite integral of Modified Bessel function, exponential and trigonometric functions
I am trying to solve the following integral;
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\gamma \cos\theta} I_{1}(\epsilon\sin\theta)d\theta,$$
where $\gamma\in\mathbb{R},\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^{+},$ and $I_{1}$ is the Modified Bessel function of the first kind, first order, defined as $I_{1}(x):=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{x\cos(t)}\cos(t)dt.$ The goal is to write the given integral in closed form.
My First Attempt:
I tried to apply one integration by parts, setting $dl=I_{1}(\epsilon\sin\theta)d\theta$ and using the differentiation formulas to get $l=\frac{\epsilon}{2}(I_{0}(\epsilon\sin\theta)-I_{2}(\epsilon\sin\theta)),$ which ends up involving, among other simple coefficients, the integrals
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\theta\sin\theta I_{0}(\epsilon\sin\theta)d\theta,$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos\theta\sin\theta I_{2}(\epsilon\sin\theta)d\theta,$$
which I do not think they seem simpler than my original one. I wonder, though, if applying multiple integrations by parts could possibly give me a pattern that might seem useful.
My Second Attempt
I substituted $e$ to its analytical expansion of infinite series, and it reduces the initial integral to;
$$2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\gamma^{n}}{n!} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^{n}\theta I_{1}(\epsilon\sin(\theta))d\theta.$$
However, I do not know if this way of writing is useful and how. And, also, it would be a bit concerning to me to force the appearance of infinite series since my goal is to find a closed form of the initial integral.
I also tried to consult the known textbook "Tables of Integrals, Series, and Products" by  I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, but I did not find anything of obvious use in my case.
Any solutions or hints or useful sources? Thank you all!

Equivalent to $$\frac{\epsilon}{4} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi }{\gamma}} \sum {m=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\epsilon^2}{2 \gamma}\right)^m \left( \frac{\pmb{L}{m+\frac{1}{2}}(\gamma)+I_{m+\frac{1}{2}}(\gamma)}{(m+1)!} \right)$$
or
$$ \frac{\epsilon}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\gamma^k}{k!}\Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right) \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right)^{2m} \frac{1}{(m+1)! \Gamma \left(m+\frac{k}{2}+\frac{3}{2} \right)}$$
with $\pmb{L}$ the Struve function.
